# Need help on kivy mapview, works on windows, but just do not work on android, app just doesn't start

Tags: kivy, android-mapview

Below kivymapview works on windows, but doesnt work on Android. Please help

```
import sys
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))

import mapview

root = Builder.load_string("""
#:import sys sys
#:import MapSource mapview.MapSource
MapView:
    lat: 50.6394
    lon: 3.057
    zoom: 13
    map_source: MapSource(sys.argv[1], attribution="") if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "osm"
    MapMarkerPopup:
        lat: 50.6394
        lon: 3.057
        popup_size: dp(230), dp(130)
        Bubble:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                padding: "5dp"
                AsyncImage:
                    source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/France-Lille-VieilleBourse-FacadeGrandPlace.jpg"
                    mipmap: True
                Label:
                    text: "[b]Lille[/b]\\n1 154 861 hab\\n5 759 hab./km2"
                    markup: True
                    halign: "center"
""")

runTouchApp(root)
```

Comment: Do you get an error? [Here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) is a tutorial on how to get errorlogs.

Comment: No.. i don't see any errors, it just that works on windows, but not on Android. May be later i need to try out with some code tweak...Still waiting to here some advise and help here :)

Comment: How are you running this on Anrdroid? Are you using Buildozer, Kivy Launcher,  or something else??

Comment: thanks John for checking with me i used Buildozer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i had this fixed, looks like i had to start fresh to build it and had to amend requirements..These examples at https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview/tree/master/examples are really good to have the mapview work on Android. Also follow this link carefully https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview for better ideas :)